# Using jZebra as a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, zpl

I have a ZPL capable printer running on a server which I would like to integrate with jZebra (http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/). jZebra, however, is for client-side printing. What would be the best implementation if I wanted to use jZebra to print to the ZPL printer connected to the server?
In other words, I want to queue jobs from a client computer to the web/print server using jZebra server-side. This will also prevent the client from needing to load a Java applet since all Java is handled on the server instead of the client.

Answer (score 0):

Use print raw directly and bypass the applet stuff.

The site has an API section that should get you started.  The mailing list will be able to help more.